# Wordpress browser language redirections - too many redirects error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to implement a redirection in my Wordpress website based on browser language, by adding this code on the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/ambienteTrabajo/?lang=es [L,R=301]
```

the `?lang=es` is how the WPML plugin labels my translated pages, however I'm not using the built in WPML redirection because it gives me an unpleasant delay: the page first loads in English and then a few seconds later redirects to Spanish.

With the code I added before the url redirection is done, but the page is not shown; it shows a blank page with a **TOO MANY REDIRECTS message**.

How should I set up this redirect rule? I've tried a lot of things without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably going into an infinite loop, because every time a page loads it will detect the language is `es` and do the redirect... which will read .htaccess, check the language again, detect that its `es` and do the redirect again etc etc.

Your redirection rules need to do the following

- if the browser language is `es`
- *and* the querystring *doesn't already contain* `lang=es`
- only then do the redirect

I'm not an expert with Rewrite rules, but try something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/ambienteTrabajo/?lang=es [L,R=302]
```

**Note:**

You will need to clear your browser cache after you remove the existing 301 redirect.

I've changed it to a 302 redirect - you should always test your rules with a temporary 302 redirect first to make sure its working *before* making them permanent with a 301 redirect, just in case something goes wrong!